# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to connect the JSF to database.

This are the files

web.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

     <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

    <resource-ref>
 <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/mkyongdb</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>


   <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
   <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

   <!-- JSF mapping -->
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

context.xml

```
     <Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/mkyongdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongdb"/>

   </Context>
```

Default.xhtml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  >
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h1>JSF 2.0 + JDBC Example</h1>

    <h:dataTable value="#{customer.getCustomerList()}" var="c"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Customer ID
            </f:facet>
                #{c.customerID}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Name
            </f:facet>
                #{c.name}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Address
            </f:facet>
                #{c.address}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Created Date
            </f:facet>
                #{c.created_date}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

    </h:body>

  </html>
```

CustomerBean.java

```
        package com.mkyong;

   import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

  import javax.annotation.Resource;
  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
  import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
  import javax.naming.Context;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;

  import com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer;

  @ManagedBean(name="customer")
  @SessionScoped
  public class CustomerBean implements Serializable{

//resource injection
@Resource(name="jdbc/mkyongdb")
private DataSource ds;

//if resource inject is not support, you still can get it manually.
/*public CustomerBean(){
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mkyongdb");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}*/

//connect to DB and get customer list
public List<Customer> getCustomerList() throws SQLException{

    if(ds==null)
        throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

    //get database connection
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();

    if(con==null)
        throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");

    PreparedStatement ps 
        = con.prepareStatement(
            "select customer_id, name, address, created_date from customer"); 

    //get customer data from database
    ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();

    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    while(result.next()){
        Customer cust = new Customer();

        cust.setCustomerID(result.getLong("customer_id"));
        cust.setName(result.getString("name"));
        cust.setAddress(result.getString("address"));
        cust.setCreated_date(result.getDate("created_date"));

        //store all data into a List
        list.add(cust);
    }

    return list;
}
    }
```

Customer.java

```
     package com.mkyong.customer.model;

     import java.util.Date;

      public class Customer{

public long customerID;
public String name;
public String address;
public Date created_date;

public long getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}
public void setCustomerID(long customerID) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public Date getCreated_date() {
    return created_date;
}
public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
    this.created_date = created_date;
}
   }
```

pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
 <artifactId>JavaServerFaces</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
<repository>
   <id>java.net.m2</id>
   <name>java.net m2 repo</name>
   <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
 </repository>
 </repositories>

   <dependencies>

<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring framework --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-b13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-b13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- EL 2.2 to support method parameter in EL -->
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ -->
     <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>





     </dependencies>

    <build>
   <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
 </project>
```

If I run this in Tomcat7 I am getting the following error

```
             SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance                   of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
       java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method   "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:636)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Jun 15, 2012 2:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
  SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    Jun 15, 2012 2:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
 SEVERE: Context [/JavaServerFaces] startup failed due to previous errors
   Jun 15, 2012 2:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader  clearReferencesJdbc
 SEVERE: The web application [/JavaServerFaces] registered the JDBC driver        [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped.       To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
 Jun 15, 2012 2:31:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 Jun 15, 2012 2:31:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
  INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 15, 2012 2:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 2341 ms
```

Can Anyone help me out to solve this.

Comment: This looks like a clash in class loading the expression-language api (el-api).Any EL jars bundled with your web-application ?

Comment: I have solved that error. el-api.jar is found twice.I have a new error.I have updated the question.Please check it.

Comment: Do you have jsf-api and jsf-impl jars in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: No,I dont have those jar files

Comment: Please do not change (chameleonize) an existing question into a different one when a problem is solved. You should instead ask a new one. Otherwise all existing ansers would become completely confusing and useless. Please also don't post a wall of code. Post only the code which is absolutely relevant to the concrete problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that JSF api and implementation jars are available for the container (tomcat) to load. Place the libraries either in WEB-INF/lib are in tomcat lib folder.

Comment: I have added those jar files.Now I am getting new error related Bean file.I have updated the question.Sorry for the more trouble

Comment: Were you able to get the datasource with the code in constructor ?

Comment: No. I am getting javax.el.ELException: /default.xhtml: Property 'customerID' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: Since I am new to this,I am not able to fix it.

Comment: The attribute `value` must be mapped to a `bean.value` and not `bean.method`.You don't have to explicitly call a method in value attribute.JSF will automatically get the value from managed bean's accessor methods. Restructure your code. Initiate `customerList` with `@PostConstruct` method.Refer in dataTable with `#{customer.customerList}` .

Comment: Refer this link for basic common tasks. http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/how-to-do-10-common-tasks-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12600/discussion-between-bharathi-and-ahamedmustafam)